# Python: Connecting to gmail server using poplib giving error

Tags: python, poplib, gmail-pop

I am trying to connect to gmail server using POP protocol using poplib library.
it fails to connect with error:socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I have network access from the machine i am running my script.

```
import poplib
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com',995, timeout=30)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Please help in rectifying this?

I got the gmail server name from the below link:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636148818957220191-1947633130&rd=3

Comment: Can you ping `pop.gmail.com` from the machine you're running the code on?

Comment: Lose the timeout argument and it should work

Comment: @Torxed: getting request timeout on ping -                                                      ping gmail-pop.l.google.com [64.233.178.108] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: same error, I am able to access internet , there is no connectivity issue

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol Then I'm guessing your DNS server is wacky or you have no internet access. This isn't a programming error as much as it is your setup/scenario that isn't properly configured. If ping is getting a timeout - then it's an obvious sign something is wrong with the network.

Comment: Same problem here. Tried in two computers, both with Ubuntu flavours. One succeeds another doesn't. Both are connected to the internet.